# IE11 in Document mode 5 doesn't fire "onresize" event in when scaling (zooming), any site

Tags: javascript, resize, scale, compatibility, internet-explorer-11

If this is a real bug, does anyone knows a workaround to deal with it?
Or maybe I'm doing somethig wrong?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open any site (for example, http://www.microsoft.com) in IE11
2. In F12 Developer tools Emulation set Document mode to 5
3. In F12 Developer tools Console run `window.onresize = function(){ console.log("onresize fired"); }`
4. Try to scale a page (for example, using  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+ mouse wheel).

Expected result: "onresize fired" is printed in the console.

Actual resut: no messages in the console.

Comment: "set Document mode to 5" Are we talking about IE 5 testing? In 2014?

Comment: `Document mode 5` should be quirks mode, right? Do you need that? Why don't you test with an actual instance of IE7 instead?

Comment: It should be IE6 testing, because next document mode is 7. Yes, in document mode > 5 the event works fine.

Comment: My app was designed in IE6 times and today users run it in IE11. Yes, we are doing a migration, but this is a mess, a long story mess...

Comment: onResize() does not fire when scroll zooming in older browsers (not sure of the exact list but pretty sure it does from IE8+) if you were to just resize the browser normally you would see this event fire

Comment: IE8 in the same situation (compability mode 5) fires the resize event. So right after an update from IE8 to IE11 a user gets the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things to consider:

- First, the console is supported only in document modes later than IE9 standards mode.  Because your test is focused on IE5 (Quirks) mode, alert or `someElement.innerHTML( "Message" )` may be more effective.
- The [resize event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536959(v=vs.85).aspx) has some behavioral subtleties that attempt to balance the differences between the behavior required by the standards against legacy (proprietary) IE behavior.  For details, see the remarks in the linked reference page.

Based on the information available, I'd call this "as designed" behavior (or perhaps "as intended"), rather than "buggy" behavior.

For your specific situation, you'll want to look at the effect that's being accomplished and see if there's a different way to trigger it.  Alternatively, you could try [IE Enterprise (EMIE) mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn255001(v=vs.85).aspx#enterprise_mode).  (Rumor has it that it does a better job of emulating older document modes.  YMMV.)

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've tried IE Enterprise, it dosen't help. Currently I think about this workaroud: catch `mousewheel` event with `ctrl` key pressed and trigger `resize` manually.